# Is $Nm_{L/K}(L\backslash K)$ Zarisky dense in $\mathbb{A}^{1}(K)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $Nm_{L/K}(L\backslash K)$ Zarisky dense in $\mathbb{A}^{1}(K)$? Here $Nm$ is the norm map for a finite field extension $L/K$. Note that we are excluding $K$ from $L$ before the map.

This is clearly true for finite field (in fact it is surjective). But for infinite field surjectivity might not be true, but is it still at least dense?

Comment: If $K$ is infinite, the image contains the infinite set $x^d$, $x\in K$, $d=[L:K]$. If this set is not dense, its closure must be a proper closed subset of the affine line. Do you know what they are?

Comment: @Mohan: ah thanks, this question is trivial then. Technically we exclude $K$ but the norm of remaining elements should remained infinite.